# How to recode missing data in R when R does not recognise the continuous variable?

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a continuous variable, with some 'NA'and for some reason when I try to look at the variable (i.e mean summary) this is what comes up:

```
Summary(THM1$Br03)
Length  Class   Mode 
     0   NULL   NULL 

 mean(THM$Br03)
 [1] NA
```

This is the output when looking at the first few rows:

```
 WSZ_Code Treatment_Code Year Month  TTHM CL2_FREE    BrO3 Colour   PH  TURB
1          2              3 1996     1  30.7    0.350 0.00030   0.75 7.40 0.055
3          7              4 1996     2  60.4    0.050 0.00055   0.75 7.10 0.055
4          7              4 1996     2  58.1    0.150      NA   0.75 7.50 0.055
```

but when i do str(THM):

```
'data.frame':   345 obs. of  10 variables:


$ WSZ_Code      : int  2 6 7 7 7 5 1 5 8 1 ...
$ Treatment_Code: int  3 1 4 4 4 2 2 2 1 2 ...
$ Year          : int  1996 1996 1996 1996 1996 1996 1996 1996 1996 1996 ...
$ Month         : int  1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
$ TTHM          : num  30.7 24.8 60.4 58.1 62.2 40.3 20.8 36.3 40.5 47.8 ...
$ CL2_FREE      : num  0.35 0.25 0.05 0.15 0.2 0.15 0.15 0.025 0.25 0.05 ...
$ BrO3          : num  0.0003 0.00055 0.00055 NA NA 0.0014 NA NA NA NA ...
```

Ok so you can see the first few values are there and then its NA but i cant summarize any of the data in that variable! i just need to have some summary statistics of the data and look at the relationship between Br03 and TTHM

When i tried this:

```
mean(THM$Br03, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(THM$Br03, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

This is what happens.

I dont know how to recode the variable to either 0, or 99 so as to analyse the variable.

Comment: There are no values in `THM1$Br03`. Why don't you paste the output from `str(THM1)` so we can see what is happening.

Comment: please dont add "HELP!!!!" to questions.  You are not drowning. You are not being pursued by an evil villan.  There is no need for the drama

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, but, we like drama :) See it got you 6 up-votes!

Comment: @Arun As evidence in favor of your point, Simon left the "HELP!!!" in when he edited, and I'm also declining to edit it out :-).  +1 to Ricardo.

Comment: First of all, thanks @RicardoSaporta for that comment. I am slightly stressed at the moment so that made me LOL.

Comment: Ok so you can see the first few values are there and then its NA but i cant summarize any of the data in that variable! i just need to have some summary statistics of the data and look at the relationship between Br03 and TTHM

Comment: I contrast to packages like Stata some commands in R don't omit missings from calculations by default. `mean(THM1$Br03, na.rm=TRUE)` might help

Comment: @RoyalTS I just tried it and the output is shown above. :/

Comment: so HOW DO I RECODE???

Comment: How are you trying to recode it

Comment: Just recode it to 99 or 00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are spelling the column name wrong: `THM1$Br03` when it should be `THM1$BrO3` (note the `O` vs `0`). That's why `THM$Br03` is NULL.

Comment: THANKS! Cant believe it was just a spelling mistake :s